# A way to enable remote admin for a specific user

Tags: windows-7, windows, administrator, remote-access

We know that there are generally two ways of enabling performing admin tasks on Windows 7 remotely:

- Enable the built-in admin account and furnish it with a password, or:
- [Set LocalAccountTokenFilterPolicy](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/942817) and then use any local admin account

Now the latter measure is a bit sweeping - it allows every local admin to do that. And the former one is too restrictive, I might want to use another account for remote administration tasks than the built-in admin.

Is there a middle ground? Specifically, is it possible to configure a local admin account, that is not the built-in admin to be able to perform remote administration similarly to how the built-in one can, but without enabling this ability for every local admin?

Comment: On a domain? If you are on a domain then you create a security group that you add to local Administrators group on the PC via Group Policy. Members then get akin rights when they log in - this is best practice. No domain: you can add individual users to the local Administrators group and this will do the same. No editing of the registry, no enabling the built-in Administrator account.